# centraliser of an element in $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbf Z)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Given a matrix $M \in \mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbf Z)$, is there a description of what the centraliser of $M$ looks like?

Here are some related facts:

1. We know that two matrices commute implying they have at least one
   common eigenvector.
2. The power of $M$ is an element in the centraliser of $M$, but the converse is not true, e.g. take $M$ as the identity matrix.
3. This [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55620/commuting-matrices-in-gln-z) gives us a description of all rational    matrices that
   commute with $M$, but not all of such matrices are in $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbf Z)$.

Any reference/ideas would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is a difficult problem, and the answer involves algebraic number fields. There are algorithms to compute the centralizer by Eick, Hoffman and O'Brien, based on work by Grunewald and Segal.

See [this arXiv paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.06190) (published in Journal of the London Mathematical Society, Volume 100, Issue3, December 2019, Pages 731-756) and the references to papers by Grunewald and Segal.